# Maximizing the probability of collisions when selecting subsets of random integer distributions

Tags: probability, algorithms

Consider two independent sets, $A$ and $B$. Each is comprised of $N$ integers selected uniformly at random and without replacement from the range $[0, R)$. Now, consider some function $F$ that takes a set $S$ with size $N$ and returns subset $S' \subseteq S$ with size $M$. What strategy for $F$ maximizes the probability that the intersection $F(A) \cap F(B)$ is non-empty ($\neq \emptyset$)?

In other words, given two random sets of integers, what strategy for picking a subset maximizes the chances of a collision?

The naive algorithm of selecting $M$ elements at random yields few matches, as expected. I began with a simple sort (selecting the smallest $M$ values), and this does much better. But I can't seem to do *any* better than this (evaluated using simulation). This problem *seems* similar to the [100 prisoners problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem) where we could somehow "spread out" the distribution of collision counts to maximize the probability of at least one collision by "sacrificing" probabilities of additional collisions (at least, that's how I think about the prisoner problem). But does that logic not apply here? Is it simply the case that any arbitrary total order will yield the same probability of collision?

In particular, I've tried the following algorithms, and their performance is not measurably different from the basic sort:

- Partition N into M blocks, then pick values closest to their centers.
- Iteratively pick M values where each selection maximizes the total absolute difference between adjacent already-selected values (and the endpoints).

*Edit:* added testing code

```
def Randomize(s, m):
    # in 100000 trials, 108 set pairs collided with 108 total collisions
    random.shuffle(s)
    return s[:m]


def Smallest(s, m):
    # in 100000 trials, 7870 set pairs collided with 8142 total collisions
    # can we do better?
    return sorted(s)[:m]


def Test():
    TRIALS = 100000
    R = 100000
    N = 1000
    M = 10
    strategies = [Randomize, Smallest]
    for strategy in strategies:
        random.seed(42)
        total = 0
        count = 0
        for _ in range(TRIALS):
            a = random.sample(range(0, R), N)
            b = random.sample(range(0, R), N)
            a2 = strategy(a, M)
            b2 = strategy(b, M)
            collisions = len(set(a2) & set(b2))
            total += collisions
            if collisions > 0:
                count += 1
        print(f'{strategy.__name__}: in {TRIALS} trials, {count} '
              f'set pairs collided with {total} total collisions')
```